# Stepping inside the drag and drop process (or any other system call)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, com

I have an application that does not use the standard libraries. Instead, it uses stubs to call LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress, then calls functions via the resultant function pointers.

Using the above method my application is calling DoDragDrop in ole32.dll. The call is returning E_UNEXPECTED, which apparently means 'catastophic failure'.

What I want to ask is does anyone know of a way to discover what is happening inside the call to DoDragDrop? Specifically, can I discover what function or variable it is looking for but cannot find? (I am guessing that it wants access to some function or variable that is not loaded at the point I call DoDragDrop, and if I can explicitly load it the call will succeed.) Obviously I can't step into the call - attempting to just runs the function and steps to the line in my code following the DoDragDrop call.

:)

(I'm using VS2005 in XP.)

Comment: I can't say I really advise it, but if you switch to the disassembly window, and then single-step, you can step into (at least the user-mode part of) a system call. Unless you're reasonably accustomed to assembly language, however, it's probably not going to do you much good.

Comment: That's kinda neat, but doesn't help because it's all gobblygook to me! But it put me onto system symbol files, and I'm currently downloading a set from MS. I'm hoping it will add something I can understand to the disassembly listing...

Comment: ...well, I've got the symbols, and I've been stepping through the code, which now makes some sense. It looks like a function called CoMarshalInterface inside a function called GetMarshalledInterfaceBuffer is failing (these are both within ole32.dll). I think my interfaces may be a bit stuffed up. AddRef, etc may not be at the front of my objects, which I think COM requires, although I've never had it fail before because of it. My head hurts now! So I'll come back to it tomorrow I think...

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put `AddRef`, as long as you inherit from `IUnknown` (as you should). Since it puts `AddRef` first, your override will remain first.

Answer (score 0):

I recall having something like this occur when I had forgotten to call OleInitialize(Ex) / CoInitialize(Ex) for the thread making the call. Note the apartment must be STA.